# PHP Accessing array element, getting strange result

Tags: php, arrays

I am writing a PHP file to be included on a bunch of pages that does authorization checks.  I'm using `debug_backtrace()` to figure out which page the user is trying to load.  I then explode the filepath string and read the last element in that array to get the page name.  For some reason, when I use `sizeof($referrerArray) - 1` to access the last element, I'm getting the page with a 1 appended.  For instance, the page I want is `CreateEntry.php` but it echos `CreateEntry.php1`.  For some reason, when I switch the access variable to `(sizeof($referrerArray) - 2` I get the proper behavior but when I echo it, it's the wrong string.

```
$backtraceArray = debug_backtrace();
$referrerArray = explode('/', $backtraceArray[0]['file']);
$lastElementIndex = sizeof($referrerArray) - 1;
$referrerPage = $referrerArray[$lastElementIndex];

if ($referrerPage != "CreateMenuEntry.php") {
    die();
}
print_r($size);
print_r($referrerArray[5]);
print_r($referrerArray[$size]);
```

my output looks like

```
"5CreateMenuEntry.phpCreateMenuEntry.php1"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where's `$size` defined?

Comment: I think that `1` is coming from somewhere else in the script.

Comment: If you want to provide it, echo something after `print_r`.

Comment: what are you doing? :-) `if ($referrerPage != "CreateMenuEntry.php") {` is it OK code flow or WRONG one? your `print_r`s must be called on the wrong flow? or in any case? for now your debug condition and outputs looks very weird for me

Comment: `rtrim($your_var, '1');` This won't do anything if there is not a 1 appended, and will remove it if there is.

Comment: So I tried this on another computer, xamp stack, (I was using preinstalled osx stack previously) and its working.  I'm not sure what was causing it to happen on my other computer though.